# Google +1 button in Market (google play)

Tags: android, google-play

I noticed that Google Play shows now a +1 button so people can say they like your application.
Is there a way to know stats about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way except for the number shown in the market. I believe Google is working on adding it to the Dev Console.